# Not able to use writeUTF() anymore after reassigning to BufferedOutputStream and FileOutputStream from DataOutputStream

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I am having trouble converse over socket using writeUTF("String") to client listen to the message using readUTF().
Up to now it worked as I wanted.  However after adding codes for receiving file from the client i am not able to send any massage to the client.  The code is the followings.  It has been days to figure it out...  Can anyone help me solve this issue?  I appreciate your inputs :-)

// Client.java

```
            String ack = in.readUTF();
            println(ack); // "How do you do?"

            String aack = in.readUTF();
            println(aack); // HANGING FOREVER
```

// Server.java

```
                Socket server        = serverSocket.accept();
                DataInputStream in   = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());




// CAN SEND MESSAGES    
                out.writeUTF("How do you do? "+ "\r\n");
                out.flush();

// AFTER THIS SEGMENT CANNOT WRITE TO CLIENT ANYMORE

                    int bytesRead;
                    int current              = 0;
                    FileOutputStream fos     = null;
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
                    try {
                        byte [] byteArray = new byte [FILE_SIZE];
                        InputStream is    = server.getInputStream();
                        fos               = new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
                        bos               = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                        bytesRead         = is.read(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
                        current           = bytesRead;
                        do {
                            bytesRead =
                                    is.read(byteArray, current, (byteArray.length-current));
                            if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
                        } while(bytesRead > -1);

                        bos.write(byteArray, 0 , current);
                        bos.flush();
                        System.out.println("File " + FILE_TO_RECEIVED
                                + " downloaded (" + current + " bytes read)");
                    }
        finally {
            if (fos != null) fos.close();
            if (bos != null) bos.close();
        }
// WORKS ALRIGHT UP TO THIS PART

// PROBLEM BEGINS...
// CANNOT                 
// SEND MASSAGE ANYMORE  
// CLIENT WAIT FOR MSG HANGING FOREVER 
             out.writeUTF("Can you hear?"+ "\r\n");
             out.flush();
```

Comment: OutputStream os = server.getOutputStream();

            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
            pw.println("What's you name?");  This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you use an OutputStreamWriter, like

```
OutputStream out = ...;
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "utf-16"));
```

Comment: You mean following part?  DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());

Comment: Yes. In fact, you can skip making the DataOutputStream and just construct it from server.getOutputStream()

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Your idea gave me insight to solve this issue!